# Replace function replaces space also . How to prevent it?

Tags: javascript, replace

In a input field on paste event i am calling method that would replace all special characters but it is also replacing empty spaces between words. How to prevent it ?

```
checkSpecialCharacters(){
    let value = this.form.get("quantity").value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g,'').replace(/\s/g,'');
    // if value = "testing value"
    console.log(value) // returns testingvalue
  }
```

what am i doing wrong here ? `[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]` adding space will not skip spaces ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.replace(/\s/g,'');` matches any space character (normal spaces, newlines, line feeds, and tab characters, both horizontal and vertical). If you want to preserve plain spaces, remove that part completely.

You can also make the pattern more concise by using the case-insensitive flag and `\d` instead of `0-9`.

```
let value = this.form.get("quantity").value.replace(/[^a-z\d ]/gi, '');
```

Comment: Thank you.. is there any specific reason for appending /gi.. what does it mean?

Comment: The `g` means that all matches will be replaced, not just one. the `i` makes it case-insensitive, meaning that you don't have to repeat `a-zA-Z`, but just use `a-z`.